# Resizing images failing

Tags: post-thumbnails

I have recently added theme support for post_thumbnails with three new sizes, I wanted to resize all the old images uploaded previously. I have written my own script as follows:

```
function resizeImages()
{

    require ( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );

    global $wpdb;
    $images = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_type = 'attachment' AND post_mime_type LIKE 'image/%' ORDER BY ID DESC");

    foreach ($images as $image)
    {
        $fullsizepath = get_attached_file( $image->ID );

        $metadata = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $image->ID, $fullsizepath );
        // If this fails, then it just means that nothing was changed (old value == new value)
        if (wp_update_attachment_metadata( $image->ID, $metadata ))
                {
                    echo $fullsizepath . " resized" . "<br/>";
                }
    }

}
```

The images that have been uploaded through wordpress work fine, but I have added some of my images by php. The images in question were picked up from our old site with a crawler and added to the database as children of the correct ID. I can retrieve all the images using get_children on the index.php page and on single.php, but for some reason they are not being resized. Can anyone help here?

Comment: Close-vote for being too localized, as essentially a "debug my code" type of question. Also, downvote for failing to follow up on/respond to answers posted.

Answer (score 1):

use this plugin instead. Always work for me :) http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails

Comment: Tried it, didn't work because problem was images had no wp_metadata, as is flagged on the plugin page, so I coded my own class to take all the images from the wp_posts db, search and find them on the filesystem to get their full path, then used wp_insert_attachment, wp_generate_metadata, and wp_update_metadata to achieve the goal.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [Add From Server](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/add-from-server) Plugin, to ensure that your PHP-added images have been added properly to the database.